# Animation status not switching when I switch to the show state for the second time

Tags: angular, typescript

In my parent component I have this method:

```
toState = 'hide';
showPopup() {
    this.toState = 'show';
}
```

and html

```
<child-component [currentState]="toState">
</child-component>
<div (click)="showPopup()"></div>
```

In child component i have this animation defined.

```
  animations: [
    trigger('popOverState', [
      state('show', style({
      height: 300,
      opacity: 1,
    })),
    state('hide', style({
      height: 0,
      opacity: 0,
    })),
    transition('show => hide', animate('600ms ease-in')),
    transition('hide => show', animate('800ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

And another Close popup method

```
@Input() currentState;

closePopup() {
   this.currentState = 'hide';
}
```

While the Child HTML looks like this

```
<div [@popOverState]="currentState" class="myclass">
    <button (click)="closePopup()" class="btn btn-success">Close</button>
</div>
```

All works as expected: I click the showpopup button in the parent..then in the child i hit the close popup and it works but as I hit the showpopup in the parent again the popup doesn't display again. I though it is an animation state problem..like show -> show and I changed the transitions to

```
transition('* => show' ...
transition('* => hide' ...
```

but i get the same results: popuo firing and hiding only first time.
How can I solve this ?

Comment: Modifying the input of a child doesn't modify the value in the parent. In this case, it's 2 way binding, not just one way.

Comment: I also thought this ..but how can i achieve the 2 way binding ? any suggestion ?

Comment: [Thoughtram has an excellent article about that](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html), if you want to check it out !